# Can't find collision layer in Unity 5.6.1?

Tags: unity-game-engine

So I have a little problem I wish you will help me to solve, I am following a course in udemy, the instructor added some gameobjects to a scene, he changed the tags, but when it comes to layers, he chose an option which I don't have in my Unity platform, he chosed collision layer but I don't have it, I was looking there and there But I didnt find someone having the same problem.

[image: a photo from the course and photo of Unity I am using]

I am new to Unity, and to gaming in general.
Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You can add layer by yourself. Just click on Add Layer...

Comment: I added One, but things does not seem to work, which means that this is not the problem, thanks anyway ..

Comment: Define "doesn't work"

Comment: You can then decide which layer collide between them. Just go to Edit -> project settings -> Physics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'CollisionLayer' is a custom layer created by your Udemy instructor. You can click on 'Add Layer...' and create a new layer with the name of 'CollisionLayer'. You can then go to 'Edit > Project Settings > Physics' and set the necessary checkboxes in the collision matrix. The collision matrix is essentially a big grid and allows for you to determine which layers collide with each other (ex. you want to prevent objects on the layer 'Projectiles' from colliding with anything on the layer 'Water').